# Return null instead of contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I hava a function in a contract:

```
  function getLastBidding() public view returns (Bidding) {
    return biddings[biddings.length-1];
  }
```

The problem is when the `biddings` array is empty, it doesn't work, because I can't access index `-1`. So, I would like to return some sort of *null* when the array is empty. What can I return instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to probably `require(bidding.length > 0);` before returning.

It will revert the request...but that's kind of the point.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of @ReyHaynes's suggestion, you can put almost anything into a dynamic array, but you'll get an error if you try to recall row `0` from a list with less than `1` row.

Consider separating concerns by returning the length of the list by itself. That way, if a client requests the first row before it exists, `error` is the appropriate response. With a `public` array, the clients can inspect by row number, starting at row 0 (if it exists).

```
BiddingStructs[] public biddingStructs;

function getBiddingCount() public view returns(uint count) {
    return biddingStructs.length;
}
```

Hope it helps.